# AWS Lambda API Gateway timeout

Tags: aws-lambda, configuration, timeout, aws-api-gateway, cold-start

I'm new to stackoverflow, so I apologize for my poor description....

I am currently running a django via aws lambda.

There are occasions of API Gateway timeout(30 sec) when running a function.
Embarrassingly, a function shorter than 2 sec gets a timeout too!

I've searched through the CloudWatch log and found the damn timeout log.

[timeout log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhmE7.png)

The funny thing is, according to my custom log, the function has started almost 1 sec before the 30 sec timeout.

What could be the problem? I am trying to evade timeouts as much as possible.

Could it be because of cold-start?

I've even set my zappa_settings.json with ["keep-warm": true] and ["keep_warm_expression": "rate(1 minute)"].

And yes, my lambda function is not inside a vpc.

As my function is also python based, my colleagues think it can't be cold-start...(I've tried everything to reduce any chance of cold-start, right?)

I am posting the full log down below.

The instance started at 02:09:52 ending at 02:10:22, where the function(i.e. 'MY_FUNCTION()') started around 02:10:21. (The function should be finished with 'MY_FUNCTION() - 4' then render the html.)

Any help would be appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uMuuwLXm5PtwgE5Rtb-jid5T-carbuGxaiUP4AUd_pk/edit?usp=sharing

> To Mrinal, below is my lambda configuration. I have added the role description on the above google docs.

[Lambda Config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syJ0t.png)

[Lambda Config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI0i4.png)

[Lambda Config3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxJxR.png)

[Lambda Config4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTf7P.png)

[Lambda Config5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UERzp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of your code. It is happening when something wrong with your Lambda Config.

```
 1. Check what Lambda Execusion Role you assign. It that have all requierd AWS Resource access or not.
```

POST Yout Lambda Config here.

Comment: I have added my config above. Please check any time available. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @MrDjh did you even find a solution for this? I'm kind of in the same situation